# Python - Adding headers back after numpy procedure

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, header

I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong here, I'm sure it's a simple fix.

I have a subsection of code that I'm running:

```
# Convert ds to datetime
cv_results['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(cv_results['ds'])

# Set ds as index
Filtered_CV = cv_results.set_index('ds')

# Drop NaNs
Filtered_CV = Filtered_CV.dropna(subset=['y','yhat'])

# Eliminate 0's
Filtered_CV = np.clip(Filtered_CV['y'],.1,np.inf)

# Filter by Time
T_CV = Filtered_CV1.between_time('05:00','16:00')

# Add column headers back
T_CV.columns = ['ds','y']

# Calculate MAPE
MAPE = mean_absolute_percentage_error(T_CV.y,T_CV.yhat)
```

The function I'm running is this:

```
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true, y_pred = np.array(y_true), np.array(y_pred)
    return np.mean(np.abs((y_true - y_pred) / y_true)) * 100
```

But I keep getting this error:
"AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'y'"

When I run:

```
T_CV.head()
```

I get this:

[image]

And when I export T_CV to excel I get this:

[image]

Clearly T_CV 'y' does exist, but it's not being recognize by the function. Any ideas? I'm at a loss.

Comment: It looks like T_CV is a Series that is already appropriately named. Just `T_CV = T_CV.reset_index()` to make it a DataFrame again?

Comment: I guess I'm not following. I've traced the loss of 'y' to the np.clip function, which I understand is due to the array handling. But 'ds' is the index, so how do I use reset_index() to get 'y' to show as a header? Seems odd to me that it would show as an excel header, but not in the dataframe.

Comment: Again. It appears `T_CV` is _not_ a DataFrame. It appears to be a Series. This seems to be the case given the print (which is in Series display markdown), the excel sheet (which is in Series spreadsheet format), and from the error message "'Series' object has no attribute 'y'"

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer. Still learning python, it's quite a bit different from what I am used to.